# How to write it in words about sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

- **(Weak) mathematically**: Let $A,B\subseteq X$. If $\sigma(\{A,B\})$ is given and that $A$ and $C$ are atoms in $\sigma(\{A,B\})$, then $\sigma(\{A,B\})=\sigma(\{A,C\})$.
- **Example**: Let $X=[0,1]$ and $A=(0,\frac{1}{2})$. Then $\mathcal{B}_{1}:=\sigma(\{A\})=\{\emptyset,A,\{0\}\cup [\frac{1}{2},1],X\}$. The sets $A$ and $\{0\}\cup [\frac{1}{2},1]$ are atoms in $\mathcal{B}_{1}$. Also note that $\sigma(\{A,\{0\}\cup [\frac{1}{2},1]\})=\mathcal{B}_{1}$.

I have tested it with other different sets and all of them worked well. Then I want to write into words:

- **Words**: Let $\sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{D}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Let $\mathcal{K}=\{A_{i}\}_{i=1}^{N}$ be a family of subsets of $X$, and assume that all elements in $\mathcal{K}$ are atoms in $\mathcal{D}$. Then $\mathcal{D}=\sigma(\mathcal{K})$.

I want to correct or make the words to make sense. The two first points above were just an example that illustrates what I want to summarize. If there is a proof to the conjecture, I'd love to know it.

**Definition**: A set $A$ in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is called an atom, if there is no proper subset $B\subset A$ such that $B\in \mathcal{A}$ (Taken from [Schilling, Problem 3.5 (i)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521615259)).

Comment: How do you define an atom?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I've updated the post.

Comment: Ok, the definition above is fine; the one in the link requires a measure..

Answer (score 1):

$X=\{1,2,3\}$, $\mathcal{F}=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, hence $\sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{P}(X)$. But $\{3\}$ is an atom of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\sigma(\{3\})\neq \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: I can't really see why $\{3\}$ is the only atom of $\mathcal{P}(X)$. If $\{3\}$ is an atom, then $|\sigma(\mathcal{F})|$ is supposed to be $2$ (see page 16-17 on http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/solutions1-12.pdf), which isn't same as $|\mathcal{P}(X)|=2^{3}$. But I would say that $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$ are atoms in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ because, other than those atoms, the set for example $\{1,2\}$ can't be an atom, since $\{1\}\subset \{1, 2\}$ and $\{2\} \subset \{1, 2\}$. So $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$ are atoms, and then $|\sigma(\mathcal{F})|=2^{3}$.

Comment: You never asked that members of $\mathcal{K}$ have to be "all" atoms of $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$..

Comment: I apologize if I didn't write it properly. I thought I wrote something like that "[..] and assume that *all* elements in $\mathcal{K}$ are atoms [..]". I actually meant the set $\mathcal{K}$ containing all atoms of $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$.